# Disable Browser session in laravel jetstream

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-jetstream

I am having laravel project version 8.23 with the jetstream

PFA image below

[image]

How to disable this part in the jetstream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In resources -> views -> profile -> show.blade.php file

[image]

comment following section

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Inertiajs & Vuejs stack, you need to comment out/remove the following line in `resources\js\Pages\Profile\Show.vue`:

```
<logout-other-browser-sessions-form :sessions="sessions" class="mt-10 sm:mt-0" />
```

[image]

Or if you're wanting to just edit the contents of the component you can edit  `LogoutOtherBrowserSessions.vue` located here:`resources\js\Pages\Profile\LogoutOtherBrowserSessionsForm.vue`.